# OData v4 Query To Filter Results In A Complex Object

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, odata, webapi

I developed a .NET Core v5 WebAPI and Integrated OData v4.
Everything works if I return a normal list of students from my controller and perform OData queries.

But my API has a standard response structure for success and failure. Everything comes only inside data property.

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Student A",
            "age": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "Student B",
            "age": 11
        },
        {
            "name": "Student C",
            "age": 12
        },
        {
            "name": "Student D",
            "age": 13
        }
    ]
}
```

What can be the OData URL Query to `fetch Students with age > 11`. This is what I tried

```
https://localhost:44351/api/v2/Students/GetAll?$filter=data/age gt 11
```

But it throws me this error
[image]

This is my endpoint.
Also I've configured OData only for search, filter, order and count. Expand is not something I'm considering now

```
[HttpGet]
[MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("Success")]
[EnableQuery]
public IActionResult Success20()
{
    var listOfData = new List<Student>();
    listOfData.Add(new Student { Name = "Student A", Age = 10 });
    listOfData.Add(new Student { Name = "Student B", Age = 11 });
    listOfData.Add(new Student { Name = "Student C", Age = 12 });
    listOfData.Add(new Student { Name = "Student D", Age = 13 });
    return Ok(new SuccessResponse<List<Student>>
    {
        Data = listOfData
    });
}
```

And this is my standard response for Sucess

```
public class Response
{
    protected ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class SuccessResponse<T> : Response
{
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public SuccessResponse()
    {
        ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.SUCCESS;
        Status = ResponseStatus.SUCCESS.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your response structure, I suppose you are returning an Anonymous Type in the API controller, code as below, right?

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var result = _db.Students.ToList();
        return Ok(new { status = "success", data = result }); 
    }
```

As far as I know, the OData is not designed to work with anonymous types (if using the above code, it will show the error you are meeting). So, to solve the error, you could create ResponseModel which contains the `status` and `data`, then return it to client and filter data.

Code like this:

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    [Key]
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<Student> data { get; set; }
}
```

API controller:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var result = _db.Students.ToList();
        //return Ok(new { status = "success", data = result });
        return Ok(new ResponseModel { status="success", data = result});
    }
```

Then, change the `EntitySet` model in the `GetEdmModel()` method:

```
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(); 
        builder.EntitySet<ResponseModel>("Students"); 
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

After that, we could filter data using url: `https://localhost:44387/odata/Students?$expand=data($filter= age gt 11)`

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ZhiLv for the suggestions. However I'm not sending out an anonymous object but a generic object. I've modified my question to include my endpoint. (Statically serving students list for simplicity)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The reason it was due to the exclution of Expand on OData.
I've added Expand() referring to @ZhiLv's answer

[image]

And the query was working now.
[image]